# read a string from a text file to a char var. Then c prints a longer string than the stored on the char var

Tags: c

I am trying to read text from a file and to print the same text on another different file. Here is the part of the code where the problem appears.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{

    char address_format[4];
    char data_format[4];

    FILE *puntinput;
    puntinput = fopen ("input.txt","r");

    fscanf (puntinput,"%s   address format\n",address_format);
    address_format[4] = '\0';
    fscanf (puntinput,"%s   data format\n",data_format);
    data_format[4] = '\0';

    fclose (puntinput);

    FILE *puntmif;
    puntmif = fopen ("signal.mif","w");

    fprintf(puntmif,"ADDRESS_RADIX = %s;   %% Address and value radixes are required  %% \n",address_format);
    fprintf(puntmif,"DATA_RADIX = %s;      %% Enter BIN, DEC, HEX, OCT, or UNS; unless  %% \n",data_format);

    fclose(puntmif);

    return 0;
}
```

where the input.txt file contains:

HEX address format
DEC data format

And the signal.mif file:

ADDRESS_RADIX = HEXDEC;   % Address and value radixes are required  % 
DATA_RADIX = DEC;      % Enter BIN, DEC, HEX, OCT, or UNS; unless  %

I have tried to add \0 character at the end of address_format char variable, but it has been useless. I don't know what else I can do.

Has anyone any idea about how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please change assigning null character to ...[3] (indexing from 0) - it is first seen mistake, searching for another.

`address_format[4] = '\0';`
`data_format[4] = '\0';`

Or extend array to 5 elements (contents + `\0`) - `fprintf()` will print string, which ENDS with null character.

Answer (score 0):

I compile your code and run it in my computer with your input. but got the output as you expect. and you should not assign anything to null pointer i.e. `address_format[4]`. use `address_format[3]` instead.